# StaticInjectorError(AppModule) window in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

How to open excel file from the location using the window?

```
constructor( private fb: FormBuilder, private http: Http, private router: Router,private window:Window) { }

window.open(this.excelURL + "report/" + this.getexportlist.data.data, '_blank');
```

It shows the below mentioned error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[CouponUsageReportComponent -> Window]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[CouponUsageReportComponent -> Window]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for Window!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Window object as a dependency injection then you have to provide it somewhere (preferably AppModule's provider array), or you can use it without injecting it.

Comment: Yes, I provided `WINDOW_PROVIDERS` in the module where StaticInjectorError error was being thrown, and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The  error says you have used window but not defined in your `module.ts` Provider ex providers: [Window]

Add it under providers in your `app.module.ts`

Comment: windows provider?

Comment: @RevathiVijay yes its Window. mark if the answer helped